# JAVA .properties file

Tags: java

having a lil issue, i have create a properties file :

config.properties located in ../resource/config.properties

this is the file currently :

```
destinationPDF=D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/
destination="D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/
fileList =D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/Directory Files/directoryFiles.txt
```

have i done the properties file ok ?

also i want to access this file and load the variables into a class

i have tried

```
public void loadProp() {
    try {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("../resources/config.properties"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("destinationPDF"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("destination"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("fileList"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but now the class will not compile becuase it can not find variable destination for example, so how do i load the variables from the file, and do i still need to declear the variable in the class ?

sorry if these are silly questions, first time using properties !

i do not get this error if i put in the variables normally like

```
private String destinationPDF = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/"; //USE ON TORNADO//"D:/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/";//USE ON PREDATOR
```

EDIT:

have now

```
private Properties configProp = new Properties();

public void loadProps() {
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../resources/config.properties");
    try {
        configProp.load(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
public void loadProp() {
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../resources/config.properties");
    try {
        prop.load(in);
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("destinationPDF"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("destination"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("fileList"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Properties prop = new Properties();
private String destinationPDF = prop.getProperty("destinationPDF");
public String destination = prop.getProperty("destination");
```

it is working, no erors etc but destination and destinationPDF are passing null values

Comment: Doesn't compile? Or gives errors while running?? Also, there are opening quotation marks on your `destination` property, but no closing ones.

Comment: _destination="D:/Documents_ is a typo or do you have like that in properties file itself? also I assume it is not finding your .properties file location. What stacktrace it is showing?

Comment: Have you defined prop variable somewhere?

Comment: sorry, it does not compile at all, it gives me the erro cariable desination is not define, and yeas the "D:/ is a type, in the real file there are no "

Comment: If your compilation error is `variable desination is not defined`, than your error is not in the code you posted above.

Comment: On what line do you get the compile error? Where is `prop` defined?

Comment: prop is not defined, i get the error when i compile, on the first line `destination` is used

Comment: @user2065929: show us the code causing the compiler error message, and the exact and complete compiler error message. Hint: the error message contains the line and column number of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what properties files are. They're just data. They don't contain Java code, and aren't used to declare variables. To get the value associated to the key `destinationPDF` in the properties file, you need to call

```
String destinationPDF = prop.getProperty("destinationPDF");
```

after having initialized the `prop` variable and loaded the file using `prop.load(new FileInputStream(...))`. And then you'll have a variable initialized with the value of the key.

Side note: please respect the Java naming conventions: variables start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: also, I don't see him calling his `loadProp()` method.

Comment: ok i have edited it, now i dont get any errors, but destination and desintationPDF is passing a null value and not the value from the file, any ideas?

Comment: You're reading values from the `prop` object *before* loading the properties file. So there's no property in `prop` yet.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand, what part of the code is in the wrong palce ?

Comment: `public String destinationPDF = prop.getProperty("destinationPDF");`: the field is initialized as soon as `new YourObject()` is invoked. And at this time, obviously, the method `loadProp()` on the object has not been called yet, since the object doesn't even exist yet. That's like trying to drink water from a recipient you're constructing. The recipient must first be constructed, then filled, and then only you can drink what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
        // destination = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/";  // main location for uploads (CHANGE THIS WHEN USING PREDATOR)
        File theFile = new File(destination + "/" + username);
        theFile.mkdirs();// will create a sub folder for each user (currently does not work, below hopefully is a solution) (DOES NOW WORK)
        System.out.println("Completed Creation of folder");
        NewDestination = destination + username + "/";
```

You have commented the destination variable and you are using here:

```
NewDestination = destination + username + "/";
```

Comment: Yes i commented out the destination variable, as i was hoping to use it from the properties file instead of declearing it in the class

Comment: @user2065929 then you should remove the code where you are using that undefined variable, that's why you are getting "destination" undefined error.

Comment: @user2065929: You have a misunderstanding of properties. See JB Nizet's answer, he explains why you can't use keys from properties files as variable names in your code.

Comment: @ user2065929 - you have the mistaken assumption that loading property files creates variables in your code. It does not. All it creates is a dictionary of string values that you can look up by (string) keys.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whats the issue...I tested your code and it works fine...are you getting compilation error or runtime error?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class Test1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1().loadProp();
    }

    Properties prop = new Properties();

    public void loadProp() {
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("c:/Test/Computer.txt"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("destinationPDF"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("destination"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("fileList"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/
D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/
D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/Directory Files/directoryFiles.txt

Comment: You have much more code than the OP. He's missing the declaration (and initialization) of his variable(s).

Comment: have posted my code above, i think i am not loading prop, is this the case ?